# Should I upgrade when a development branch becomes stable?

Tags: upgrade

I have an alpha version of Ubuntu.

When the stable version is released do I have to upgrade or is it already stable from the installed updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` will get new repo lists and packages as they are released and ultimately, you will have the same packages installed as the final release, including the various bugfixes as the version transitions from  -

Alpha -> Beta -> Release Candidate -> Stable Release

You **do not need to** 'fresh install' the stable version later.

For Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet), the release schedule is -

[image]

Comment: Should i do apt-get dist-upgrade or apt-get upgrade?

Comment: Unless you need to upgrade to a newer kernel, I see no reason why `dist-upgrade` needs to be preferred over `upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want upgrade all package using always the terminal use:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```