# Upgrading from 16.04 daily to 16.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, touchpad, lenovo, touchscreen

I have a Yoga 900 and I would really like to install Ubuntu on the machine. But the [trackpad and touchscreen do not work in Ubuntu](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204355) natively.  There is a fix by [installing Ubuntu 16.04 daily on Yoga 900](https://allanbogh.com/2015/12/23/installing-ubuntu-16-04-daily-on-a-lenovo-yoga-900/) and then installing kernel 4.5.

I'd like to install Ubuntu before the full LTS release of 16.04 so I am wondering if I follow the instructions above and install 16.04 daily now will it be possible to upgrade to the LTS version when its released?  Are there potential problems of doing things this way?

Comment: 16.04 *Should* become 16.04 LTS at the release date - at least that was the way it worked with 15.10!  I would still recommend that you make regular, frequent backups and be prepared to re-install.

Comment: 16.04 is still pre-release so ... apt-get update and it will turn into 16.04 LTS post release.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I upgrade when a development branch becomes stable?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/571325/should-i-upgrade-when-a-development-branch-becomes-stable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to upgrade from the daily release to the eventual full release of Ubuntu 16.04 by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But you would be running a pre-release version of Ubuntu that could *potentially* be very unstable and you could easily lose all of your work. Your entire system could also become unusable. These are the perils of running pre-release versions..

Your *safest* bet is to hold off until the full release date which should be April 21st.

**References:**

- [Xenial Xerus: Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule)