# Upgrading 16.04 beta 2 to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

I was about to do a fresh install of 14.04 LTS, but I just saw that 16.04 will be released in less than a month. If I were to install 16.04 beta now, would it be easy to upgrade to the official release in April? Also, how stable is the current beta2 build? Is installing it substantially risky despite it being so late in the development cycle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I upgrade when a development branch becomes stable?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/571325/should-i-upgrade-when-a-development-branch-becomes-stable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, the beta version of Ubuntu will either upgrade automatically to the release or ask you if you want to do so via the update manager, once the release comes out.  But be warned: the updated version may be "eccentric" if you don't do a fresh install of the release version.

Comment: So what does eccentric mean here? Is what you're saying that the upgraded beta 2 won't actually be identical to the final version and therefore it should be avoided?

Comment: I've done this kind of upgrade a couple of times, with other versions, and, for some reason, the upgraded version would sometimes have inexplicable errors, like a program that doesn't launch, or apt not getting dependencies right, etc.  It might have been a bug with the update manager of those versions, but if it's a production system, I would strongly recommend doing a fresh install, just to be safe.

Comment: thanks, that's the info I was looking for. I think upgrading from the RCs was even supported, but alphas and betas were not.

Comment: Thanks, I tried installing 16.04 but it was somewhat buggy, so I'll just wait for the official release.